# How do I write a simple add-on for Firefox Mobile using page-mod with addon-sdk-1.17?

Tags: android, firefox, mobile, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I tried to write a simple add-on for `Firefox Mobile` with `addon-sdk-1.17` using `page-mod`, and I failed.
My device for testing is `Samsung SGH-I927` with `Android 2.3.5` on board with both `Firefox Mobile 34` or `Firefox Mobile Beta 36` installed.
The add-on I've found in [this article](http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/02/06/mobile-add-on-development-using-the-add-on-sdk/) should do exactly what I want, but apparently it doesn't work with my device or `addon-sdk-1.17` anymore, I don't know why.
Ok, I can't use `contentStyleFile` because of this [bug 1107240](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1107240).

So I tried to simplify that add-on to do at least something:
`main.js`

```
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: '*',
    contentScriptFile: './content.js'
});
```

`content.js`

```
console.log('test');
window.console.log('test');
unsafeWindow.console.log('test');
document.title = 'test';
window.document.title = 'test';
unsafeWindow.document.title = 'test';
```

And it doesn't do anything. `adb logcat` shows nothing. Then I tried to simplify it even more:

`main.js`

```
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: '*',
    contentScript: 'window.alert("test");'
});
```

Still nothing.

So how do I write a simple add-on using `page-mod` that does work?

**UPDATE:** I tried to run that add-ons on `Acer A500` with `Android 4.4.2` on board. Still no use.
And of course that add-ons work just fine on Desktop `Firefox`.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong. `page-mod` doesn't work on `Firefox Mobile Beta 36` because of [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1123295) and *DOES WORK* on `Firefox Mobile 34` when `cfx`'ed with `--force-mobile`.

Comment: Any idea if it works now? There currently on version 43, I believe.